# R shiny widget: drop the manual down

Tags: r, shiny

In this [shiny application](http://shinyapps.org/apps/p-hacker/), you can click on the manual button to drop a window down.

Would you have a sample code to achieve this?

Comment: It's a [bootsrap collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp), see the code in the Collapsible Panel of that page. That shiny application was probably built with an `index.html` and `server.R` like [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot!